# Hibernate : Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

Exception : 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not extract ResultSet

The HQL that i have written is as follows:

```
select sm from SystemMessage sm 
left join sm.systemMessageMaps smrm 
left join smrm.role r
left join smrm.projectGroup pg
left join smrm.assessmentVersion av 
left join smrm.severity sms
where ( (r.id is NULL) and (pg.id is NULL) and (av.id IN (:assesmentVersionID) ) 
         or(pg.code =:projectGroup and av.id IN (:assesmentVersionID) and  r.id is NULL) 
         or(r.name =:roleName AND av.id IN (:assesmentVersionID) and pg.id is NULL)
         or( r.name =:roleName and  pg.code =:projectGroup AND av.id IN (:assesmentVersionID) ) 
       ) and 
      ( ( sm.startDate is null or sm.startDate <= current_timestamp ) and ( sm.endDate is null or sm.endDate >= current_timestamp)) 
order by sms.priority,smrm.severityRank,sm.startDate
```

I happen to get this exception after i added in the in clause to the parameter:

```
av.id IN (:assesmentVersionID)
```

and i set the parameter value as

```
query.setParameterList("assesmentVersionID", assessmentVersionIDList);
```

i wonder where have i gone wrong!

Comment: I am using Hibernate and BatchPreparedStatementSetter is Batch update callback interface used by the JdbcTemplate class. Doesn't sound relevant does it?

Comment: Yeah, m sorry, deleted the comment

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the parenthesis:

```
select sm from SystemMessage sm 
left join sm.systemMessageMaps smrm 
left join smrm.role r
left join smrm.projectGroup pg
left join smrm.assessmentVersion av 
left join smrm.severity sms
where ( (r.id is NULL) and (pg.id is NULL) and av.id IN (:assesmentVersionID) 
         or(pg.code =:projectGroup and av.id IN (:assesmentVersionID) and  r.id is NULL) 
         or(r.name =:roleName AND av.id IN (:assesmentVersionID) and pg.id is NULL)
         or( r.name =:roleName and  pg.code =:projectGroup AND av.id IN (:assesmentVersionID) ) 
       ) and 
      ( ( sm.startDate is null or sm.startDate <= current_timestamp ) and ( sm.endDate is null or sm.endDate >= current_timestamp)) 
order by sms.priority,smrm.severityRank,sm.startDate
```

This should work, if not try removing the parenthesis from `(:assesmentVersionID)` too.

Let me know if it solves the issue.